# TypeDoc not working

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, jsx, typedoc

I'm trying to set up TypeDoc to build the documentation from a TypeScript project.

```
typedoc                              \
    --out ./docs                     \
    --theme minimal                  \
    --name MyProject                 \
    --readme ./README.md             \
    --mode modules                   \
    --target ES6                     \
    --includeDeclarations            \
    --externalPattern "node_modules" \
    --excludeExternals               \
    --hideGenerator                  \
    ./src/
```

Typedoc would simply emit the USAGE and exits. There is no other error message. I also tried:

```
typedoc --mode modules --out ./docs/ ./src/
```

Doesn't work either. I also tried writing a typedoc.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    out: './docs',
    name: 'MyProject',
    readme: './README.md',
    externalPattern: 'node\\_modules',
    hideGenerator: true,
    target: 'ES6',
    jsx: 'preserve',
    experimentalDecorators: true
};
```

and specifying this on the console:

```
typedoc --mode modules --options typedoc.js src/
```

To no avail; all I ever see is the USAGE string.

I spent two hours trying to debug typedoc to see what's going on, and I suspect TypeDoc doesn't see any source files at all. I also tried specifying the `src/main.ts` instead of just the directory `src`, but this didn't help either.

I'm at a loss, I can't get this thing to work. Any ideas?

```
$ typedoc --version
TypeDoc 0.4.4
Using TypeScript 1.8.10 from /usr/lib/node_modules/typedoc/node_modules/typescript/lib
```

Comment: Fixed it by downgrading to 0.5.1 (was >0.5.2 before). Dunno what exactly caused it.